# How to visualize this dependency in a use case diagram

Tags: dependencies, use-case-diagram

Lets say a user saves something client side, now the system wants to synchronize it to the database. Do you visualize the dependency like this:
(client side operation)< - - - - - (cloud synchronization);
or like this:
(client side operation) - - - - - >(cloud synchronization);

The client element triggers the synchronization element but the synchronization element is dependent on the client element so i am a little confused what is the best way.